# Emacs auto-indent in Clojure - Do it like CL?

Tags: emacs, clojure, common-lisp, auto-indent

Emacs auto-indents Clojure code in the following way:

```
(defn foo [x]
  (if (= 0 x)
    0
    1))
```

I'd prefer if it did it like Scheme and CL:

```
(defn foo [x]
  (if (= 0 x)
      0
      1))
```

How do I change my .el files to make this happen?

Comment: I, too, dislike this indentation style. I think indentation in Lisps should be syntax-level, not semantics-level, i.e. always lining up with the item above. (but I'm probably the only one)

Comment: This is a personal preference thing, but I very much recommend you grow accustomed to the first.  It's what the rest of the Clojure community uses.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't really test this, but it seems to work (in clojure-mode):

```
(put 'if 'clojure-indent-function 3)
```

Comment: Works for me. Just put it into my `.emacs`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't do code blocks in comments:

Elisp isn't indented in either of the ways you mention:

```
(if (test-p foo)
    bar
  baz)
```

Common-lisp-mode indents that way, too. Scheme-mode lines them all up.

Comment: Emacs 23.4.1 seems to ship with a Common Lisp mode that also lines them all up too.